# error al hacer PIVOT Dinámico sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Buen día.

Estoy generando un query pivot dinámico pero al ejecutarlo me sale un error y no logro hacer que funcione. Lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT *
    FROM ( Select rfc, concepto, unidad
               FROM v_campos_personalizados 
               where concepto in (     SELECT STUFF(
 (
 SELECT
   ',' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(concepto))
 FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT concepto
    FROM conceptos_nomina cn 
   ) AS T
 FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, '')

)
         ) As source
 PIVOT
  (
    SUM(unidad)
      FOR concepto in (' + (SELECT STUFF(
 (
 SELECT
   ',' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(concepto))
 FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT concepto
    FROM conceptos_nomina cn 
   ) AS T
 FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, '')) ')
     ) as P
```

Y el error que me sale es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que será lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Así no se puede hacer un código dinámico. Necesitas utilizar `EXEC()` o `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Por cierto, ese no parece un error de SQL Server